# Diagonalizable transformation on exterior square (wedge product)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ denote a finite dimensional vector space. Let $\Lambda^2(V)$ denote the wedge product of $V$ with $V$. If $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$, then $T$ naturally induces a transformation on $\Lambda^2(V)$:
$$\hat{T}(v\wedge w) = T(v)\wedge T(w).$$
Can we say about *when $\hat{T}$ is diagonalizable* by putting some conditions on $T$? (i.e. I want to know the following kind of result if any: *if $T$ satisfies this condition, then $\hat{T}$ is diagonalizable.*)

(Note that, if we want to talk about diagonalizability of $\hat{T}$ without considering anything about $T$, then this question simply reduces to diagonalizability of a linear map on finite dimensional vector space, and there are some criteria for it.)

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are looking for is the following: *If $T$ is diagonalizable then $\widehat{T}$ is diagonalizable.*

First of all: $dim_{\mathbb{R}}V=n,$ so $dim_{\mathbb{R}}\Lambda^2(V)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$

Suppose $T$ diagonalizable; and let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ the eigenvalues of $T$, and $v_1,...,v_n$ the respectively eigenvector of $T$.

By the definition of $\widehat{T}$ we have:

$$\widehat{T}(v_i\wedge v_j)=T(v_i)\wedge T(v_j)=\lambda_iv_i \wedge\lambda_jv_j=\lambda_i\lambda_j(v_i\wedge v_j),$$

so $v_i\wedge v_j$ are eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda_i\lambda_j$.

**Question:** How many product of $\lambda_i\lambda_j$ we have? It's not difficult to see that they are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ counted with multiplicity (maybe different products can give the same real value).

In the same way we can see we have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ eigenvectors, moreover they generate the vector space $\Lambda^2(V)$.

Finally: we have proved that the number of eigenvalues counted with multiplicity is equal to the dimension of the vector space. If two (or more ) different products are equal: *i.e.* $\lambda_i\lambda_j=\lambda_k\lambda_l$ the eigenvectors $v_i\wedge v_j$ and $v_k\wedge v_l$ are linearity independent since they belong to a basis, so the sum of dimension of the eigenspaces are equal to $dim_{\mathbb{R}}\Lambda^2(V)$. Then $\widehat{T}$ is diagonalizable.

I think, but I don't have a proof now: that the converse is also true.